# Firebase getChildrenCount() showing 0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've tried everything but couldn't solve this problem.
Firebase getChildrenCount() showing 0, when I restart then Activity it showing 0.
But when I start the Activity for first time after app open it show's right data.
I tried to find log Error for onCancelled for ValueEventLisener but their is no Error.

Please help me to solve this problem.

**My Code**

```
 uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
       friendsRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Friends");
       friendsRef.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               if (snapshot.exists()) {
                  int Friend = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount();
                   friendsCountTv.setText(Integer.toString(Friend));
               }else {
                   friendsCountTv.setText("0");
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
               Log.e("ERROR/",error.getMessage());
           }
       });
```

**My DataBase**

```
"Friends" : {
    "QygAGx6eszWENoVvEdaL1uEwFxW2" : {

        "hLEGHsnKunew0NTqOH8dd4TnzfZ2" : "true",
        "stg15QKZFhNmTCYrgL5PtQ4wxJf2" : "true"
      },
     "hLEGHsnKunew0NTqOH8dd4TnzfZ2" : {

        "QygAGx6eszWENoVvEdaL1uEwFxW2" : "true",
        "stg15QKZFhNmTCYrgL5PtQ4wxJf2" : "true"
      },
     "stg15QKZFhNmTCYrgL5PtQ4wxJf2" : {

        "QygAGx6eszWENoVvEdaL1uEwFxW2" : "true",
        "hLEGHsnKunew0NTqOH8dd4TnzfZ2" : "true"
      },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no children in your Database Child Ref.

```
"stg15QKZFhNmTCYrgL5PtQ4wxJf2" : {
        "QygAGx6eszWENoVvEdaL1uEwFxW2" : "true",
        "hLEGHsnKunew0NTqOH8dd4TnzfZ2" : "true"
 },
```

Maybe if the structure is like this, it is considered to be children.

```
"stg15QKZFhNmTCYrgL5PtQ4wxJf2" : {
        "CHILD NAME" : {
           "PROPERTY" : "VALUE",
        },
        "QygAGx6eszWENoVvEdaL1uEwFxW2" : "true",
        "hLEGHsnKunew0NTqOH8dd4TnzfZ2" : "true"
      },
```

Hope this is the issue.

If this is the case, then use `snapshot.getValue().size()` to retrieve the properties length.